# Why doesn't Excel auto-adjust formula when a row is moved?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a simple spreadsheet with just one formula, which auto-increments the number in the first column, going from cell A6 down.  So the value in A6 is hard-coded 1, then A7 contains the formula =A6+1.  I then autofilled the rest of the first column with that formula, and sure enough each cell in column A has the formula, and the displayed numbers are 1, 2, 3, etc.

But if I select a row and move it up or down by Shift-dragging, the formula in cell A disappears and is replaced with the hard-coded former contents.  WHY?  I can find nothing in the preferences to explain this major dysfunction.

This is Excel 2011 on Mac.

Thanks for any insight!

Update: So I guess Excel is just fundamentally broken, at least on the Mac.

Comment: Shift-dragging? What do you mean by this? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Use `=ROW()-5` instead.

Comment: Shift-dragging means to hold the Shift key down while dragging.  It appears to be the only way to move a row in Excel, since "cutting" doesn't cut at all; the row remains in place, even after you "paste" it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.  That may work in this case, but it still doesn't answer the question of why Excel isn't auto-adjusting the formula as it's supposed to.

Comment: 1. I'm not familiar with 'shift-dragging'. It does nothing for me but I'm currently on 2007 so maybe it was introduced later. 2. I don't believe this is true: "the formula in cell A disappears and is replaced with the hard-coded former contents". 3. I don't believe this is true: "since "cutting" doesn't cut at all; the row remains in place, even after you "paste" it elsewhere". Perhaps if you were to post a more detailed description of what actually happens (including screenshots?) we could help work it out.

Comment: I don't see a use case for wanting 'cut row 13, paste it into row 9 and have the formula auto adjust from `=A12+1` to `=A8+1` ; you already have that before you moved any cells. So it's not actually clear what you might be trying to do. If you cut row 13 and paste into row 9, now you have `=A12+1` in `A9` and I can't see a valid case being made for that to behave any way *other* than that.

Comment: The use case is the same as the one for the auto-filling behavior: The formula is adjusted automatically for the position in which it's being executed; it's relative.  There's no logic in deleting the formula altogether and replacing it with a hard-coded value. I guess it's moot now, though, because I've updated to the latest version and Shift-dragging doesn't even do anything...